# NSMutableArray addObject overwrites data SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to add nsmutabledictionaries into my nsmutablearray but when the addobject is executed it overwrites the previous data with the new. If i try to add a string it works fine, but if i try to add a nsmutabledictionary it doesnt work fine. I know this question is stated before but it seems that i can not find it for the swift language. This is my code below:

```
    @IBAction func logAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    let product_name = data2[buttonRow].name
    let product_price = data2[buttonRow].price
    let product_id = data2[buttonRow].id

    productDictionary["product_name"] = product_name
    productDictionary["price"] = product_price
    productDictionary["id"] = product_id

    let string = product_name
    productArray.addObject(productDictionary)

    print(productArray, "order ends here")

}
```

I have as globals the following variables :

```
var productArray = NSMutableArray()
var productDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're working with `NSMutableArray`s and `NSMutableDictionary`s instead of Swift's native `Array` and `Dictionary` types?

Comment: The reason i am using NSMutableArray s and NSMutableDictionary s is that i need to make an array that consists dictionaries and arrays with dictionaries inside those dictionaries. For example in the specific viewcontroller that i am calling this function i need to construct an array that has dictionaries inside it and then add this array to another array. I tried to use the native Array and Dictionary but i was not able to handle it. I couldnt find also a good tutorial for nested arrays and dictionaries so...

Comment: You can certainly do this with the Swift native types, but unlike in Objective-C, you have to specify the type of data that they contain. To create a dictionary like your `productDictionary`, which I assume has `String`s for keys and `String`s for values, you'd initialize it like `var productDictionary = [String : String]()`. To create an array of these, you use `var productArray = [[String : String]]()`. And on purely stylistic grounds, you may want to call the dictionary simply `product` and the array `products`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your `logAction()` is called, you're changing the value of the *global* `productDictionary`. Since `NSArray` doesn't store *copies* of the values that you add to it, you're simply adding another *reference* to the global dictionary every time. If you're going to stick with using `NSMutableArray`s and `NSMutableDictionary`'s (see my comment on your original post), then get rid of the global `productDictionary` and instead create a *new* one each time `logAction()` is called. In other words, replace

```
productDictionary["product_name"] = product_name
productDictionary["price"] = product_price
productDictionary["id"] = product_id
productArray.addObject(productDictionary)
```

with

```
var productDictionary = NSMutableDictionary() 
productDictionary["product_name"] = product_name
productDictionary["price"] = product_price
productDictionary["id"] = product_id
productArray.addObject(productDictionary)
```

And what does `let string = product_name` do?

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you. The     string variable is there just for testing. Thank you very much.